# May I compare strings by > < in c++

Tags: c++, string, comparison

Exacly as stated in the subject: May I compare strings by `>` , `<` in c++.
I get no errors but not sure will I always get good result?

```
string a = "aabbsd", b= "bsdds";
cout<<(a<b);
```

Is the result is just a luck?

Comment: Doesn't take long to look at a reference and see what they do.

Comment: What you mean by string? you mean the length!?

Comment: It's lexicographic comparison btw.

Comment: It's okay to do it with `std::string` because it has overloaded operators to perform such operations. However this will not work preferably for `char const *`s as it will compare the pointers, not the characters.

Comment: As long as you are using `std::string`, then this is fine.  This wouldn't be fine if you were using a c-style `char*` string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Nothing wrong in it. Only thing to note is that the complexity of operation is linear.

Comment: @RobertKilar: So when using comparison in some algorithm, you should be aware of its impact on overall algorithms complexity.

Comment: In the overwhelming majority of common cases, the fact that the operation is linear is irrelevant.  The comparison finishes as soon as the first non-equal character is found.  So unless you tend to have a lot of strings which share a significant prefix, you will not experience linear behavior.  In fact, in many, if not most, if not nearly all cases, the behavior is as O(1).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: We must take care of worst case, which is O(n) and it is not a minority case.

Answer (score 1):

This will trigger a lexicographical comparison. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp):

```
operator==,!=,<,<=,>,>=(std::basic_string)
C++  Strings library std::basic_string   

template< class T, class Alloc >
bool operator==( basic_string<T,Alloc>& lhs, basic_string<T,Alloc>& rhs );
(1) 

template< class T, class Alloc >
bool operator!=( basic_string<T,Alloc>& lhs, basic_string<T,Alloc>& rhs );
(2) 

template< class T, class Alloc >
bool operator<( basic_string<T,Alloc>& lhs, basic_string<T,Alloc>& rhs );
(3) 

template< class T, class Alloc >
bool operator<=( basic_string<T,Alloc>& lhs, basic_string<T,Alloc>& rhs );
(4) 

template< class T, class Alloc >
bool operator>( basic_string<T,Alloc>& lhs, basic_string<T,Alloc>& rhs );
(5) 

template< class T, class Alloc >
bool operator>=( basic_string<T,Alloc>& lhs, basic_string<T,Alloc>& rhs );
(6)
```

Compares the contents of two strings.
1-2) Checks if the contents of lhs and rhs are equal, that is, lhs.size() == rhs.size() and each character in lhs has equivalent character in rhs at the same position.
3-6) Compares the contents of lhs and rhs lexicographically. The comparison is performed by a function equivalent to std::lexicographical_compare.